# How to pass an argument with python on commandline to perform actions on .txt and generate output

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, command-line-arguments

How can we program this with python? which lib?

If “program_name input_file column_no pattern” is executed, print the strings from the given column only if the pattern is
contained in them.

For example, `./awkward contacts.txt 1 mi`

The output will be:

```
Amit
Pramit
```

If “program_name input_file column_no ^pattern ” or “program_name input_file column_name pattern$” is executed, print
the strings from the given column only if:
      a) the strings starts with the given pattern (if ^pattern is provided)
      b) the strings end with the given pattern (if pattern$ is provided)

For example, `./awkward contacts.txt 1 ^Am`

The output will be:

```
Amit
```

Comment: Look into python subprocesses. They can be used to perform some commandline functions: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: It looks like you want to get the command-line arguments. `sys.argv` is what you need: it holds as a list the strings passed as arguments to the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass arguments from the command line, try using `sys.argv`. This will give you a list of arguments used.

For example, let's say `example.py` contains this code:

```
import sys
print (sys.argv)
```

Now, if you execute it with arguments it will give you the list of arguments you passed to it, as strings. The first argument will always be the name of the program:

```
>>>python example.py arg1 arg2
['example.py', 'arg1', 'arg2']
```

From there, open the .txt file and use readline() and regular expressions to output only the lines you want.